# JSON HTTP Request Not Working on Mac OSX

Tags: javascript, html, json, macos, xmlhttprequest

I have been using an HTTP request in a JS file to retrieve information from a local JSON file. It works just fine on my Windows computer in Firefox and Chrome, but when run on a Mac, the Chrome debugger throws an error saying that `Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP`...
My HTTP request code is as follows:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "sample.json", true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        var status = xhr.status;

        if ((status >= 200 && status < 300) || status === 305) {
            var myData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            window.myData = myData;
            showAll(myData);
        }
    }
};

xhr.send(null);
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is a security issue. You need to run this on a server, and the `file:///` protocol is not supported for such kind of requests!

Comment: @Lau — Of course not. You can't send HTTP headers without HTTP.

Comment: "Any ideas?" — Install an HTTP server.

Comment: @Quentin my bad, read it too fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a security issue. You need to run this on a server, and the `file:///` protocol is not supported for such kind of requests! AJAX is a proper HTTP request response kind of concept and you cannot use `file:///` protocol or use different protocols for the transaction.

Comment: Okay, but how come it was working fine on Windows when we are both using Chrome?

Comment: The browser you are using might be pretty old. New versions of Chrome and Firefox on the Stable channel are very strict in these kind of CORS.

Comment: There are 100s of free HTTP servers available for Mac. Use MAMP, AMPPS, XAMPP, etc. `:D`

Comment: Could it be because, on Windows, I am using NetBeans to run the project on a server, and on the Mac, we are just dragging the HTML file directly to the browser?

Comment: There you go! Yes. NetBeans by default runs on either Apache HTTPD Server or TomCat Server! `:D`

Comment: NetBeans is also available for Mac. You can do the same way you do in Windows! Trust me, it is easy!